# default time for an image to expire

Tags: image, caching, browser

I pushed some changes to one of our images to web server, but I found it's not updated on IE and firefox web browsers due to browser caching, since I saw the browsers didn't even request for image from server.

I have two choice. One is to update the image file name and re-deploy. The other is to let our users' browsers think the image exipires.

I haven't set anything in header or in code, here is the response:

```
Content-Length  32042
Content-Type    image/png
Last-Modified   Wed, 09 Nov 2011 18:41:50 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Fri, 09 Dec 2011 01:26:03 GMT
Connection  keep-alive
```

So I am wondering how soon it can expire?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if your last-modified time stamp changes, everything should take of by itself. You can set up cache-control http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/02/02/suppress-caching-of-certain-mime-types-like-gif-jpg-etc.aspx to avoid it.